# Hollywood movie that took longest to create

Tags: production, american-cinema

What Hollywood movie did take longest to create? By 'the longest' I mean full production until it made it to the theaters.

Comment: I'm sure _Boyhood_ took a while.

Comment: That would be my winner, as it was designed from the start to be in continuous production for so long, it wasn't an accident of scheduling.

Answer (score 4):

If the *John Carter (2012)* answer from Dr R Dizzle isn't what you are looking for this it's this:

[It's a box office](http://forums.itsboxoffice.com/65970/which-film-took-longest-to-time-complete) & [Yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081012021149AASA6TC) offer the answer.

**The Thief and the Cobbler**

The animated movie The Thief And The Cobbler holds the record for a movie to be in production for the longest time. It was in production stage for 31 years. (1964-1995)
Then there's Love & God (1986) directed by K.Asif. He started the film in color after Mughal-E-Azam casting Guru Dutt & Nimmi. Guru Dutt died in 1964, shooting came to a halt. Then, Sanjeev Kumar was taken in the place of Dutt, but Asif himself died in 1971. The film was left incomplete. Later in 1986, Asif's wife revived the film & released it in the incomplete form. Sadly, one year before it's release, even Sanjeev Kumar died.

Comment: I think Pakeezah took longer to complete. Work was started in 1956, after which Meena Kumari and Kamaal Amrohi seperated, It was started in B/W and then Kamaal Amrohi restarted the project when color technology arrived on the scene. The film was finally released in 1972. The song Inhin logon ne was shot on July 16, 1956.

Answer (score 2):

Although this might not be exactly what you are looking for, *John Carter* (2012) first entered production in 1935 as a hand drawn animated film, which means *John Carter* was in production for nearly 80 years before it was eventually released.

Comment: But can this really tracked down to ultimately be the same project developed over all this time? Or was it just someone starting a new John Carter project now end then, dropping it again and then someone else making a new try years after that?